# SQL: Find min date of a last type change

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a log table like this:

```
line    Date                    status  Type
1   26.04.2016 08:58    IN  4
2   26.04.2016 08:59    OUT 80
3   26.04.2016 09:05    REZ 7
4   26.04.2016 09:06    IN  7
5   26.04.2016 09:22    EDIT    81
6   26.04.2016 09:23    EDIT    80
7   26.04.2016 09:24    OUT 80
8   26.04.2016 09:25    OUT 80
9   26.04.2016 09:25    OUT 80
```

"date" is the key.

I want to get last type change date. In this example last type is "80" and the min date of it is 26.04.2016 09:23 (line 6).

I know the last type at this point (@lasttype = 80).
But if I run `select min(date) from table where type = @lasttype`, then I get line 2 instead of line 6.

How can I get min date of last block of "type" (line 6) **in one query**? I don't want to use several select after and after.

I have just try this but line 6 doesn't come again:(

```
select max(date)
from
(
    select min(date) as date, type
    from MYTABLE
    where type = '80'
    group by type
) as t1
```

Is there a easy way?

Many thanks.

Edit:
Ok, I can get line 6:

```
select min(date) from MYTABLE where date > (select max(date) from MYTABLE where type <> @lasttype)
```

Any more effective code?

Many thanks for your answers...

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Sql 2014

Comment: How come line 6 is the minimum for Type 80? Line 2 has time lesser than that. Also what do you mean by "last Type Change date"? Does the status column plays any role in your requirement?

Comment: Hi Akanksha, I have to find last type changing time. In this example, it was "4" firstly, then change to "80" then change to "7".... But it has been changed at 09:23 to "80" (line 6). And at line 7-8-9, type has not been changed. So, i try to find line 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can get line 6:

```
select min(date) from MYTABLE where date > (select max(date) from MYTABLE where type <> @lasttype)
```

Any more effective code?

Many thanks for your answers...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select min(date) from MYTABLE where Type=@lasttype
group by Type
```

Comment: Sorry, it returns line 2. I want to get min date of last type block (must get line 6 in line 6-7-8-9).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you like to retrieve last time, you better use max instead of min function, check the below:

```
select top 1 type,max(date) as date from MYTABLE group by type order by max(date) desc
```

Comment: Nope. I returns line 9. I want to get min date of last type block (must get line 6 in line 6-7-8-9).

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query

```
select max(a.Date) from 
(
 Select top 4 * from table order by Date desc
)a;
```